# Is there a simple way to process an html form upload with python?

Tags: python

As we all know the simplest way to upload a file in php is with this code :

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

I want a method to upload a file with python the simplest as possible, a file from the current directory like this:

```
import anyuploadmodule
upload(file)
```

Is there a such module can do this ?

Comment: Try [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't anything quite *that* simple out there, but micro-frameworks like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) can be lightweight and simple starting points. You'll want to checkout the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#file-uploads). Here's a snippet to get you started:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = '/some/path/'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))
    return '''<!doctype html>
              <title>Upload new File</title>
              <h1>Upload new File</h1>
              <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
                <p><input type=file name=file>
                <input type=submit value=Upload>
              </form>'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: thanks xj9 but it didnt work :/
i added r.text and i keep get the html script code : 
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: Do you want to upload a file *using Python* or do you want to upload a file using an HTML form and *save or process it* using Python?

Comment: yes processing it like a post in html form with python

Comment: `uploaded_file` should be `upload_file`?